# check if $_GET parameters are correct

Tags: php, get

I have three $_GET variables and I want to check if they are correctly being passed.

```
$amnt = $_GET['amnt'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];

if ($_GET != 'amnt' || $_GET != 'from' || $_GET != 'to' ) {
    $errorno = 1100;
    echo $errorno;
    exit;
```

I have tried this so far, however this just checks the parameters inside the $_GET rather than the acutal amnt=&from= etc. As someone could put in ammount=&frommm=

Comment: Why do you care more about the names than the actual values?

Comment: You need to write a test that checks if each parameter contains an acceptable value. We can't tell you how to do that since you haven't said what values are considered acceptable.

Comment: I already have an if statment in place to check if the values are null as well as decimal places etc

Comment: So what do you want this to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Firstly, your code will always result in a fail condition because you are comparing an array with strings and they will never be equal. Secondly, all you need to do is `if (!isset($_GET['amnt'], $_GET['from'], $_GET['to'])) {`

Comment: my url will is localhost/convert.php?amnt=1.0&from=USD&to=GBP, all i want to do is write a check to make sure that only 'amnt', 'from' & 'to' is being written in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just check if a certain parameter you're interested in is set and if so, use it. Like:

```
if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    // use $_GET['from']
}
```

If you require a certain number of parameters to be set, check for them all:

```
if (isset($_GET['from'], $_GET['to'], $_GET['amnt'])) ...
```

If any other parameters are set or if the parameters are misspelled, ignore them. If you really want to check that no other parameters are set, you can do so like so:

```
if (array_diff_key($_GET, array_flip(array('amnt', 'from', 'to')))) {
    // some other keys are set!!
}
```

But what's the point, really? If you just ignore those parameters, who cares? And additional parameters can be useful for debugging, like `example.com/foo?DEBUG=true`. If you check too strictly, you're only creating problems for yourself later.